# How to make card stick to bottom of page with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNJJEN) with a project that I'm working on and I am having an issue with the UI. I need the bottom container to fill the remaining space in the viewport. It is a bit hard to view on codepen unless you have it to the right/left of the editing spaces. It needs to stay below the top row, but not overflow past the height of the page at all (the app should all be viewable on one page). I have tried flex-grow and flex-shrink, but none of them seem to do anything to it. Here is the bottom row (without the many list items for conciseness).

```
  <div class="row flex-shrink-1" style="margin-right: 0px;margin-left: 0px;width: 100%;min-width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="col-auto col-md-6 flex-fill" style="max-width: auto;padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 10px;">
      <div class="card d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-fill" style="min-height: 100%;height: 100%;">
        <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);padding: 5px;">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md border-white border rounded navigation-clean-search" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);padding: 5px;">
            <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="max-height: auto;padding: 5px;">
          <ul class="list-group text-truncate" style="min-height: 100%;height: 100%;">
            <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.list-group.text-truncate {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.navigation-clean-search {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .navigation-clean-search {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.navigation-clean-search .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
}

.navigation-clean-search .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #222;
}

.navigation-clean-search .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.navigation-clean-search .navbar-toggler:hover,
.navigation-clean-search .navbar-toggler:focus {
  background: none;
}

.navigation-clean-search .navbar-toggler {
  color: #888;
}

.navigation-clean-search .navbar-collapse,
.navigation-clean-search .form-inline {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
}

.navigation-clean-search .navbar-nav a.active,
.navigation-clean-search .navbar-nav>.show>a {
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navigation-clean-search.navbar-light .navbar-nav a.active,
.navigation-clean-search.navbar-light .navbar-nav a.active:focus,
.navigation-clean-search.navbar-light .navbar-nav a.active:hover {
  color: #8f8f8f;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navigation-clean-search.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

.navigation-clean-search.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #465765;
}

.navigation-clean-search.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navigation-clean-search.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #37434d !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navigation-clean-search .action-button,
.navigation-clean-button .action-button:active {
  background: #56c6c6;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #fff !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.navigation-clean-search .action-button:hover,
.navigation-clean-search .action-button:focus {
  background: #66d7d7;
}

.navigation-clean-search .form-inline label {
  color: #ccc;
}

.navigation-clean-search .form-inline .search-field {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.3s;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .navigation-clean-search .form-inline .search-field {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.navigation-clean-search .form-inline .search-field:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;max-height: 100%;">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Navigation-with-Search.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body style="min-height: 100%;max-height: 100%;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-primary" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;">Lorem Ipsum</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="button" style="padding-right: 12px;">Log In</button></div>
  </nav>
  <div style="max-width: auto;">
    <div class="container" style="min-width: 100%;padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 100%;">
      <div class="row" style="width: 100%;min-width: 100%;margin: 0px;">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-6 flex-fill" style="max-width: auto;padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 10px;">
          <div class="card d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-fill" style="min-height: 100%;height: 100%;">
            <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);padding: 5px;">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md border-white border rounded navigation-clean-search" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);padding: 5px;">
                <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin-right: 8px;">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                    <form class="form-inline ml-auto" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-search ml-auto" style="margin: 0px;"></i>
                      <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control search-field" type="search" id="search-field" name="search" placeholder="Team Number" style="padding-left: 6px;"></div>
                    </form><button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" style="margin-left: 8px;">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" style="max-height: auto;height: 340px;padding: 5px;">
              <ul class="list-group text-truncate" style="height: 100%;min-height: 100%;">
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto col-md-6" style="filter: blur(0px) brightness(100%) hue-rotate(0deg) invert(0%) saturate(100%);max-width: auto;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 10px;">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body" style="padding: 5px;">
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L_jWHffIx5E" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
              <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md border-white border rounded navigation-clean-search" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);padding: 5px;">
                <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin-right: 8px;">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                    <form class="form-inline ml-auto" target="_self">
                      <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="formCheck-1"><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">Lorem Ipsum</label></div>
                    </form><button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" style="margin-left: 16px;">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-shrink-1" style="margin-right: 0px;margin-left: 0px;width: 100%;min-width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-6 flex-fill" style="max-width: auto;padding-right: 5px;padding-left: 10px;">
          <div class="card d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-fill" style="min-height: 100%;height: 100%;">
            <div class="card-header" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);padding: 5px;">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md border-white border rounded navigation-clean-search" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.03);padding: 5px;">
                <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;">Height of this card should be to bottom of viewport</a></div>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" style="max-height: auto;padding: 5px;">
              <ul class="list-group text-truncate" style="min-height: 100%;height: 100%;">
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item" style="margin: 3px 3px;">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                    <div class="col text-center align-self-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" type="button">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit for clarity:
[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WsN7.jpg) shows that there is still more to the container below the page, but since overflow is hidden, it cannot be seen. It should just overflow inside the container and fit on the screen, but it does not. I hope that helps. It seems like I would have to do something with max-height, but I'm not really sure what as 100% does not work.

Comment: i quite didn't get which bottom row you're talking about but did you try `display: flex` on parent and `flex: 2` on child? Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_equal_height_flexbox

Comment: It did not seem to work, I tried it with `display: flex` on the block and `flex: 2` on the container, `display: flex` on the container and `flex: 2` on the row, and `display: flex` on the row and `flex: 2` on the column, all to no luck.

Comment: The question really doesn't make sense as it's described. In some cases the height of the first card will be to tall to show *any* of the bottom card if you never want it to exceed viewport height. Are you saying you want the left to cards 50/50 height next to the video?

Comment: Hm...I understand what you mean, I hadn't thought about that. I think it would be better to rethink how it is going to be laid out. Thank you, sorry for the time-waster!